# How to jump to the other side of selected text?

Tags: keyboard, textselection, osx-mavericks

I have selected a text with the cursor.

Now I want to jump to the other side of the text, but how?
If I made the selection with the mouse and moved the selection once with <kbd>⇧</kbd>+ <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>, I don't find a way to change the cursor position to the other side of the selected text.

**Is there any way to make it happen. Maybe a script in PHP/Shell/Applescript?**

*I am using OS X Mavericks.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while, but I have found a way.
I use KeyBindings of OS X to reset the side where the cursor of the selection is, by killing the selection and yanking it in one step.

You need to add the following line to your `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file:

```
"$ " = (deleteToMark:, yankAndSelect:);
```

If you do not habe such a file you can create and add the line with this command:

```
echo $'{\n\t"$ " = (deleteToMark:, yankAndSelect:);\n}' > ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
```

Now the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> can be used to reset the side on which the text insertion cursor is, when you have text selected.

#### Example:

1. Select Text
2. Hold <kbd>⇧</kbd> and expand the selection on one side with the arrow keys (like <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> expands the selection on the left side)
3. Hit <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>
4. You can now decide again which side to expand, instead of only expanding/reducing one side (like <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> expands the selection on the right side)